# World music tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Shouldn't there be a tag for world music? If you are asking for, for instance, a musical style that you cannot place geographically, that would probably be the most appropriate tag.

Comment: That's not what world music means: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_music. And world music just means non-western music and I gaurntee there is a better way to describe the music you are talking about then using a world music tag.

Comment: Yes, and since this is an English speaking website in a world that is dominated by Western/American pop culture, that is what the question above will imply 90% of the time. At the very least, questions about "international music" needs its own appropriate tag. I still believe world music is the most appropriate tag.

Comment: I still don't see why we need a tag for what you are talking about. If it applies to all music then it shouldn't need to be tagged with a "this applies to all music" tag, just the specific subject you are talking about like in this case. Using a well known phrase to talk about a specific concept that is unrelated is not something I want to do for our tags.

Comment: Whether or not what @Avatrin describes as world music is correct, I think it would be a good idea to have a world music tag.  If I wanted to ask a question about Gamelan orchestras or traditional Chinese music, how else would I tag my question?

Comment: @johnny_boy tag the specific type of music. Wold music lumps way too many unrelated types of music together.

Comment: I think a world music tag would be usefull too.

Comment: @Bebs I agree, for example, I listened some songs on videogame called `Saints Row II` and one of its radio stations plays `world music`. Maybe other user would simply refer to this music as `world music`. If maybe other user know exaclty which type of genre/type of music is, s/he can edit the tags.